# Two examples of Metal struct sizes seem to contradict each other

Tags: metal, metal-performance-shaders

The size of this struct is 36 bytes:

```
struct Mat
{
    enum Type { Lam, Met, Dia };
    int type;
    packed_float3 albedo;
    packed_float3 emissive;
    float roughness;
    float ri;
};
```

That makes sense when `float`s and `int`s are 4 bytes each and a `packed_float3` is 12 bytes.

The size of this is 88 bytes:

```
struct Cam
{
    packed_float3 origin;
    packed_float3 lowerLeftCorner;
    packed_float3 horizontal;
    packed_float3 vertical;
    packed_float3 u, v, w;
    float lensRadius;
};
```

That makes sense when `float`s are 8 bytes and the `packed_float3` is 16 bytes.

These are in the same Metal shader. What is happening with the alignment here that would cause this to be true?

I can only get the match to work if a `packed_float3` must fit within a contiguous 16-byte space, so in the first example it fits right after the first `int`, but in the second example each must start its own. Is that it? If so, this magic number `16` does not appear to be documented anywhere I can find in the Metal Shading guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just counting wrong. This:

```
struct Cam
{
    packed_float3 origin;
    packed_float3 lowerLeftCorner;
    packed_float3 horizontal;
    packed_float3 vertical;
    packed_float3 u, v, w;
    float lensRadius;
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
struct Cam
{
    packed_float3 origin;
    packed_float3 lowerLeftCorner;
    packed_float3 horizontal;
    packed_float3 vertical;
    packed_float3 u;
    packed_float3 v;
    packed_float3 w;
    float lensRadius;
};
```

That's 7 `packed_float3`s, for 21 `float`s, plus a lone `float` for a total of 22 `float`s. When `float` is 4 bytes, that's 88 bytes. There's no contradiction.

Comment: You’re totally right! This is simply an issue of code readability. Now I remember why I was taught to never put multiple variable declarations on the same line inconsistently with the others.